# onTap: only static members can be accessed in initializers error

Tags: dart, flutter

Help, when i call `myMethod` in the `onTap` attribute of either a `GestureDetector` Widget or an `InkWell` widget, i get an `only static members can be accessed in initializers` error

```
static String seat1Source = 'images/carSeatBlack.png';

  _stater(){
    setState(() {
        if(seat1Source == 'images/carSeatBlack.png'){
          seat1Source = 'images/carSeatGreen.png';
        }else{
          seat1Source = 'images/carSeatBlack.png';
        }
    });
    }

  var seat1 = new InkWell(
    onTap: () => _stater(),
      child: new Image.asset(
    seat1Source,
    height: 30,
    width: 60,
   )
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `InkWell` variable by a function like this

```
_buildButton(){return new InkWell(
    onTap: () => _stater(),
      child: new Image.asset(
    seat1Source,
    height: 30,
    width: 60,
   )
 );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around than the already mentioned is that you put that variable "seat1"
into the "Widget build(BuildContext context){}" function, as I think you're trying to initialize it into the constructor.